# Csv file not Downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to download a `.csv` file from a list. I am writing code for this but file will not download

Following is my code:

```
List<AssetsDto> assetList = client.DownloadCsv(sessionData.CompanyId, locationId, assetStage, projectType, projectId, labelSize, labelMaterial, searchText, isSearch);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}", "Asset Id", "Sub Id", "Child Id", "BarCode", "QRCode", "No Of Barcode", "Label Content", "Label Size", "Label Header", "HW") + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (AssetsDto singleRecord in assetList)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9}", singleRecord.AssetId.ToString(), singleRecord.SubAssetId, singleRecord.SplitId, singleRecord.Barcode, singleRecord.QrText, singleRecord.Quantity.ToString(), singleRecord.LabelContent, singleRecord.LabelSize, singleRecord.Header, singleRecord.HW) + Environment.NewLine);
        }



        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        ViewData["PrintLabelCount"] = assetList == null ? 0 : assetList.Count();
        ViewData["LabelMaterial"] = labelMaterial;
        return PartialView("_PrintAssetListWithPaging", assetList);
```

Comment: What does client.DownloadCsv do? You've not posted the details of that code so it would be exceptionally difficult for someone to look at what you've provided and be able to add guidance.

When you debug your code is assetList ever populated?

Comment: in above code in string builder all data appended i.e append all data in sb ,here sb show comma  separated data also.but problem in downloading file